# echo part of array? PHP

Tags: php, file-handling

Can someone please tell me why my code is echoing the whole array instead of only the two values i declared in `$list` I hardly know any php so can someone tell me whats wrong?

```
if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
    if( $_POST['filmnamn'] != "" && $_POST['betyg'] != "" && $_POST['link'] != "" && $_POST['photo'] != "" && $_POST['description'] != "") {
        $myFile = 'demo.txt';
        $titel = $_POST['filmnamn'] . ";" ;
        $betyg = $_POST['betyg'] . ";" ;
        $link = $_POST['link'] . ";" ;
        $photo = $_POST['photo'] . ";" ;
        $desc = $_POST['description'].PHP_EOL;
        $data = "$titel$betyg$link$photo$desc";
        $list = "$titel$betyg";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
        fwrite($fh, $data);

        fclose($fh);

        $handle = fopen($myFile, 'r');
        $fileinfo = fread($handle, filesize($myFile));
        $fileinfo_array = explode(';', $fileinfo);
        foreach($fileinfo_array as $list){
            echo $list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You did know you were writing $data to your text file not $list and so $data contains all the incoming fields not just the 2 fields in $list.

Comment: i know that, but i need it to write all the data to the txt file because i need the other data for later, and for now i only need to print the two first elements in the text file...

Comment: use fgetcsv() to open your  text file rather than fread and then just loop through the resultant array you want elements [0] and [1] http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php 3 lines of code will do it for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `$list` but then you overwrite it in the `foreach`.

```
$list = "$titel$betyg";
```

Then you do

```
foreach($fileinfo_array as $list){
    echo $list;
}
```

Where it becomes each item of the array. You can either `echo` out just `$list` or use:

```
$list = explode(";", $list);
array_pop($list); //remove last blank item
foreach($list as $item){
    echo $item;
}
```

**EDIT:**

This will read in the file line by line and build an array

```
while (!feof($handle)) {
   $lines[] = fgets($handle);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Nex you want to echo out the information:

```
foreach($lines as $list){
    //use my above code
}
```

Note: look into [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: ok i can see that so the foreach should'nt be there at all? if so what to replace it with?

Comment: list as item doesnt work for me and if i only echo out the list its working but then the ; is also comming with the text, and that I dont want?

Comment: it works but why does it print over the previus when i type in new values and submits?

Comment: @spovell what do you mean prints over the previous? If you want, you can change the variables so you're not reusing `$list`

Comment: maybe this exceeds the question but i mean that in the end i want to print out the two values in a dynamically created list element and want to be able to print out new listelements with the new values submited from the form, but now when i fill in the form a second time it removes the first values and replaces it with the new ones?

Comment: @spovell this is because you don't really save the values anywhere when using plain `$list`. You would have to read the file (like @Charlie suggested) and echo out the values. Using my method was strictly for printing out the values just entered

Comment: ok, i understand, so even if i echo them out in a list-element they wouldnt be saved?

Comment: @spovell see my edit on reading and `echo`ing out all the lines

Comment: ok thanks alot for the help, will take a look at it later, now i must eat to be able to think again :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of giving an echo of the one variable:

```
print_r($list);
```

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
fwrite($fh, $data);
```

you write all the array element before to the file; it should be

```
fwrite($fh, $list);
```

**EDIT :**

simply directly access the element if it's just two;

```
$fileinfo_array[0];
$fileinfo_array[1];
```

or you can use [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php);

Comment: I need to write all the elements to the text file but i only need the two first elements to print out..

Comment: then it only writes the two first elements in the array every time i push submit, I need it to print out the new values each time, so its 0,1 first time then 5,6 then, 10,11 and so on..

Comment: where is $fileinfo_array[5] value? you just have 5 element.

Comment: if you submit the form twice for example the elements in the txt-file would go from 0-9 and submit three times it would be 0-14 and so on

Comment: the is only 5 elements in the form but you should be able to submit the form alot of times and each time it should only print out the two first values of the form, once 0,1, twice 4,5, three times 10,11

Answer (score 0):

this line:

> fwrite($fh, $data);

you write all the array element before to the file; it should be

> fwrite($fh, $list);

EDIT :

simply directly access the element if it's just two;

> $fileinfo_array[0]; $fileinfo_array[1];

or you can use array_slice();